# Java Development in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm a developer and am brand new to Linux (**Ubuntu**): I'm wondering what the "best practices dictate" for what FHS directories to install various tools to. Things I'll be installing:

- Eclipse & plugins
- GlassFish
- SVN
- ...etc.

I see that /opt is for holding additional ("optional") software packages, but also see /usr as a place for utils and apps. In another post a user recommended I create an entire partition for /srv alone, and to do my staging there (I assume he meant that /srv is where GlassFish and other servers should go?).

So basically: **what FHS directories do Linux developers use for which type of tools?**

Thanks for any input here

Comment: What distribution are you using?  This will partially affect how and where the files are stored.

Comment: Sorry about that! Ubuntu (64-bit); also edited this in original post

Comment: `/opt` is enough for me, I don't need another `srv`. Instead, for those standalone packages, I would create subdirectories under `/opt` and then group them inside. For example `/opt/game/foobar` or `/opt/java/glassfish`

Comment: Thanks! So, for starters, maybe I create a separate partition for /opt and put all my tools in there, like /opt/java, /opt/eclipse, /opt/svn, etc.? Do you foresee any problems with that setup?

Answer (score 0):

Generally Eclipse, GlassFish, SVN, and any other tools will be installed wherever the maintainer of the packages decided they should go.  Different distros have different preferences, but it'll just make your life more difficult if you're not installing things through the package manager.